# Finding a particular sequence

Tags: combinatorics

You have a structure like this one:
$$0) \ a|b|c|d$$
You can notice that it is made by 4 letters and 3 slashes. Letters stand for generic integer numbers. Let's call this one, just for simplicity, a structure of level 3 (as the number of slashes). Now, you define the associated structures of level 2 (so with two slashes) to $0)$ as it follows:
$$1) \ a b|c|d$$
$$2) \ a|bc|d$$
$$3) \ a|b|cd$$
(When you see two close letters it's supposed to be a multiplication between them) 
Using the same rule, and fixed for example $1)$, you can get the associated structures of level 1. They are:
$$4) \ a bc|d$$
$$5) \ a b|cd$$
Those of first level associated with $2)$ and $3)$ are:
$$6) \ abc|d$$
$$7) \ a|bcd$$

$$8) \ ab|cd$$
$$9) \ a|bcd$$
But actually you can see that there are only three different structres of first level, because some identical are repeated. The 3 different ones are $4) 5) 7)$. 
By summarizing this example, if you consider the number of structures for each levels you have:
$$1\rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 3$$
If you start with a four level structure, if I'm not wrong you should get:
$$1\rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 6 \rightarrow 4 $$
I'd like to generalize these examples in order to obtain a general result.
So, starting from a structure of level $N$ you get $N$ structures of level $N-1$, and then?
$$1\rightarrow N \rightarrow ? $$

Comment: This is not an answer, but it looks like the progressions $1\to3\to3$ and $1\to4\to6\to4$ are binomial coefficients. In this case, it is $\binom{3}{0}\to\binom{3}{1}\to\binom{3}{2}$ and $\binom{4}{0}\to\binom{4}{1}\to\binom{4}{2}\to\binom{4}{3}$. Have you investigated this ?

Comment: Really interesting, I didn't think about it; maybe one answer will prove it @Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with an $n$-level structure, you will get the sequence of binomial coefficients $\binom{n}k$ for $k=n,n-1,\ldots,1$, and if you allow **no** separators, you’ll get $\binom{n}0$ at the end. The reason is straightforward: at level $k$ you can keep any $k$ of the $n$ possible separators.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that essentially the structure of the $k$-th level are the ways to place $k$ slashes into $n$ positions (with $n+1$ being the number of lettters), i.e
$$\binom nk,
$$
as was already suggested in a comment.